# Why is selenium code not responding after the first few steps?

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div class="servers single">
            <div class="server offline" data-id="66aeRK4VwPjGBVLx">
            <div class="server-body" data-id="66aeRK4VwPjGBVLx">
                <div class="server-infos">
                    <div class="server-title">
                        <div class="server-name">
                            Devialcraft                        </div>
                    </div>
                  ... rest of the code....
```

this is the HTML code of an [this element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EPHj.png)  that I want to click on the website. There are two parts to this. first when the website is getting loaded, the code has to login, which it is doing perfectly fine everytime. But on the [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EPHj.png)  that is then getting loaded after the login the code is doing nothing.

This is the error it is showing in the chromedriver console:

```
[8540:4296:1028/151825.747:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(976)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[2360:14272:1028/151934.638:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

You can also see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zblyr.png) to find what the error is.

This is my complete code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

browser = uc.Chrome()
browser.get('https://aternos.org/server/devialcraft')
browser.refresh()
time.sleep(1)
username = browser.find_element_by_id("user")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("Not_Breadbutter")

time.sleep(2)
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("my_password")

time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_id("login").click()

time.sleep(2)
browser.refresh()
#AFTER THIS, THE FURTHER CODE IS NOT BEING EXECUTED.. IT IS NOT RESPONDING
browser.refresh()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.server-name").click()

time.sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.btn.btn-huge.btn-success").click()
time.sleep(9)
browser.quit()
```